# Tortoisesvn creating a branch and switch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, switch-statement

This might be a dumb question but I'm unable to understand:

When we create a new branch, why do we need to 'switch'? What does this 'switch' exactly do? Can't I use the whole repository as I was using earlier without bothering about switch?

Comment: No question is a dumb question if you have done your due dilligence prior to posting and some reading and still don't get it.  ESPECIALLY with Subversion.  While Subversion is very powerful and light (after you REALLY get to know it), it's NOT easy in the beginning or even over time when you encounter scenarios you've never had to deal with before.  If anyone tells you this is a dumb question, they're ignorant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switch changes the association between your working copy and the path on the server. You can branch from your working copy from trunk (for maintenance) and continue hacking away - still on trunk.

Comment: @Benjamin: Isn't this association saved somewhere inside .svn directory?

Comment: Yes, it is. That's what the switch updates/changes: The reference or association to the server repository path.

Comment: What about switching on a single folder in your working copy...does the same?

Answer (score 3):

Using switch will update your working copy to use the new branch you just created.

As an example, if you create a branch from your trunk, you will probably want to switch your working copy over to the branch you just created so that you can make edits, etc.

Comment: You can just let your working copy the way it is, and check the new branch out in another folder.

Comment: @Trevor: Does that mean if I'm working on 'trunk' and a 'branch' simultaneously, I've to switch between these 2 everytime? As you've explained, answer is probably yes?

Comment: Switching is optional. If you have two working copies (trunk and branch), then you don't need to switch. Switching is helpful when you only have one working copy and want to switch between branches or trunk.

Answer (score 0):

In the Branch / Tag dialog there is a button at the bottom called "Switch working copy to new branch/tag" selecting that will switch you automatically to the newly created branch.

I wish there was a way to automatically check that box but there isn't :(